# php files keep getting double line breaks

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-studio-code, filezilla, line-spacing

I code custom plugins for Wordpress. I use Microsoft Visual Studio Code to do the coding and FileZilla to transfer the files.

With almost every php file that I code, I'm not sure if it's something that's happening when I download my plugin and then upload it to a new site, or if it's when I install it on a new site from a zip file, but when I check the code I find that the entire code has ended up with double line breaks!

i.e.,

```
function gdvcaddons_admin() {
    add_menu_page("GD Addons Settings", "GD Addons Settings", "administrator", "gdvcaddons-settings", "gdvcaddons_settings_page");
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'gdvcaddons_admin');
// DEFINE OPTIONS TO BE SAVED //
function gdvcaddons_settings() {
    register_setting( 'gdvcaddons-settings-group', 'recaptcha_site_key' );
    register_setting( 'gdvcaddons-settings-group', 'recaptcha_private_key' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'gdvcaddons_settings' );
// DECLARE FILE CONTAINING OPTIONS FORM //
function gdvcaddons_settings_page(){
  include('inc/gdvcaddons-settings-form.php');
}
```

Becomes:

```
function gdvcaddons_admin() {

    add_menu_page("GD Addons Settings", "GD Addons Settings", "administrator", "gdvcaddons-settings", "gdvcaddons_settings_page");

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'gdvcaddons_admin');

// DEFINE OPTIONS TO BE SAVED //

function gdvcaddons_settings() {

    register_setting( 'gdvcaddons-settings-group', 'recaptcha_site_key' );

    register_setting( 'gdvcaddons-settings-group', 'recaptcha_private_key' );

}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'gdvcaddons_settings' );

// DECLARE FILE CONTAINING OPTIONS FORM //

function gdvcaddons_settings_page(){

  include('inc/gdvcaddons-settings-form.php');

}
```

It is quite a problem because it keeps causing Yoast SEO's sitemaps to break and I keep having to open all my php files via FTP and do regex search/replace "\s\n" with "\n".

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue and how I can prevent it from reoccurring?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `transfer type`

**For single FTPs**

[image]

**Global Settings.**

[image]